# Multi-threaded Application w/ 'console'

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have an IRC bot I use for some stuff at work. The main logic of the bot is within a while True: statement.

What I'd like to do is make the application multi-threaded. It will just run the main app, but also have the ability to accept input on the console.

I *think* it would be something like this...

```
from threading import Thread

def mainFunction():
    while True:
        doStuff

def consoleInput():
    while True:
        readAndProcessConsoleInput

t1 = Thread(target = mainFunction)
t2 = Thread(target = consoleInput)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Am I way off here? Does anyone have a resource that specifically deals with this type of program architecture?

Comment: For arbitrary threads you are on the right direction, but if your threads are of specific nature (e.g. web server, rest api, zmq communication,.. etc) more specialiced frameworks/solutions exist. You also have to have in consideration if `mainFunction` and `consoleInput` have to share information or not.

Comment: They dont really share information. The only thing they would share is the connection to IRC, but thats stored outside both functions.